# How can I make this code shorter in JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to make my code shorter, I was trying to do some arrays etc. but is not working. Do somebody can help me?

```js
// Task 1
var firstBox = document.getElementsByClassName('box1')[0]


firstBox.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {

  event.target.style.backgroundColor = "purple";

}, );

firstBox.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event) {
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}, );
```

Thank you, 
Megi

Comment: This is a 7 line script. What do you expect concerning *shorter*?

Comment: You could shorten the js code by deleting it all and using css 'hover' instead.   ie, #box1:hover{ backgroundColor : white}

Answer (score 1):

There is not much you can do to make it shorter but I suppose you could use jQuery.

```
$( "#id" ).mouseenter(function() {
 $("#newColor").css("background-color","purple");
});

$( "#id" ).mouseleave(function() {
 $( "#newColor" ).css("background-color","white");
});
```

Comment: I don't have more questions. Thank you for your help.